# Magento 2 "Whoops, our bad" on every product page

Tags: magento2, 404-page, product-page

The products are shown in category view. But, once clicked, the product page is not shown, but instead, a 404 `Whoops, our bad…` message is displayed.

I tried clearing the cache and was not able not find the re-index option that is mentioned in other questions.

The `system.log` and `exception.log` shows nothing when the error occurs.

Any idea why is it broken and how to fix it?

Comment: 1 up for question because you do latest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try re-indexing using the Magento 2 CLI

[ssh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) into the server where your Magento files are and go into your Magento root folder.

`cd /var/www/html/magento2`

From that folder you can access the magento 2 cli with

`bin/magento`

***If you can't start it, use* `chmod +x bin/magento`**

in order to re-index data via the CLI, use the following command

`bin/magento indexer:reindex`

If you want to be sure that NO cache is kept, you can remove the following folders from the `var` directory with:

`rm -rf var/cache var/generation var/pagecache var/di`

and then re-compile magento using command

`bin/magento setup:di:compile`

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: Thanks @denish it did re-index. But the re-index did not solve the 404 problem.

Comment: clear all cache and re compile. it may help.

Comment: nope. I tried compiling by `sudo bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` which still left me with 404. It only broke my theme :)

Comment: this command only generates static files it not compiled. try with
php -f bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: now I get `500` and the nginx log shows: `Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Config\Scope::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\AreaList, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given,`

Comment: ok, found it `https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3963`. the solution was: `rm -rf var/generation/ var/di/`

Comment: thanks @denish vachhani. would you like to summarize the answer and I'll mark it as correct or should I do that?

Comment: check updated answer. and most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Please check all product entity(Ids) available in "**sequence_product**" table.
Need product id in that table to init product page.

Comment: This was the exact problem when we migrated from M1 -> M2. Thanks for the help :)