# Getting error in Magento Admin panel "Whoops, our bad..."

Tags: magento2, php, error

Please help me to find out the issue of "Whoops, our bad...". I have tried other solution but not getting success.

[image: magento-]

Comment: I followed it but not getting success. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110468/magento-2-whoops-our-bad-on-every-product-page

Comment: Are you getting this error on all admin pages or any specific page?

Comment: only admin pages right now. store URl working fine

Comment: I think any extension is doing conflict. Can you try to disable custom modules?
Earlier I also got this type of issue for CMS page and it was due to custom extension.

Comment: Now its working. Actually I have added custom admin panel URL when doing installation first time. But that UEL is not working right now. So, I have check the admin URL using cmd and hit in the browser. Now its working fine

Comment: That sound great !!

Answer (score 1):

1) Please check Magento file permission, specially `pub/static` , `var/` , `generated`

2) Check your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

3) Check .htaccess at root of magento, is it available or not.